# Ubuntu Studio Backports

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio, backport

I'm currently running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.  I thought that I read somewhere that the Ubuntu Studio backports is set up so that I can use the backports to essentially update Ubuntu Studio without upgrading the Ubuntu portion to 22.10, 23.04 etc.  Did I misread that?  Has that been implemented yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what you read, we can't tell you if you missread or not.

You can check [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=jammy) which packages the backports ppa provides for `22.04`.

Using the backports ppa enables you to use newer versions (from `22.10` or `23.04`, backported to `22.04`) for only certain packages, it is not a substitution for a relase-upgrade, your base system is still `22.04`.